# Looking for a UNIX shell script to aggregate and report on video file size, bitrate, and other attributes

Tags: ffmpeg, script, ffprobe

hope everyone is staying safe and healthy in this crazy time.
I've got a large, well organized repo of video - mishmash of raw video from shoots along with edited files, in all sorts of various standard formats.

I'm looking for a script that can start at a path, and report back on all the files it finds, with a combination of information from the file system *and* ffprobe (or ffmpeg). I'm especially interested in readable file sizes, resolution and bitrate.

After failing miserably on my own, i found Paul Mennen's "vidtime.bat" script, here: http://www.mennen.org/misc/batch.htm

This appears to be precisely what I'm looking for (sample output from Paul's web site is included below). My problem is that it's an old Windows script (even though it uses sed); I really need it to run on Mac OS or Ubuntu, preferably in bash. My problem is also that I can't script for s**t. If anyone knows of something that already exists that does this, or wants to make suggestions and/or take a crack at porting Paul's script, that would be amazing. I think a lot of people could really use something like this.  Cheers!  -moe

Excerpt from mennen.org:

```
Here is a sample output file. When the script was invoked, the current folder contained 10 video files and no subfolders:

************* Total run time 12:22:26 ******************* 10 video files, 4.8 GB 
00:01:02   221 kbs  mpeg1   320x240      1 MB  .wmv  ---  Anticipation
01:20:16  1045 kbs  h264   1280x720    629 MB  .mp4  ---  Before Sunset 2004
00:05:15   531 kbs  flv1    640x480     20 MB  .flv  ---  Benjamin Franklin
[...]
```

Comment: Does it need to be recursive? That is, are there also subdirectories that need to be probed too?

Comment: @llogan - yes, it would be ideal if the script traversed its way downward/recursively from an initial path.  but if you have something already that doesn't do that one thing, I'm all ears. :-) thanks!

Comment: This question is asking for a lot, and would be too time consuming to write an answer, but you can definitely do most of it with ffprobe. Search Stack Exchange for usage examples and see [FFmpeg Wiki: ffprobe tips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) for more.